# fiddler to calculate page load time of a silverlight application

Tags: performance, fiddler

I have a silverlight application, that I want to calculate page load time through C# using Fiddler API. Could you please share some useful guidelines how I can do it using fiddler/fiddlercore. Here are some details what I want to do...

1. Launch fiddler and launch IE (without using httpweb request)
2. Load my application url.
3. Calculate page load time

Earlier I tried to use httpwatch API to calculate it. Httpwatch do all these stuffs, but it doesn't calculate the silverlight component load time.

Please help.

Thanks,
Pritam